# GWTBootstrap - Masking Datepicker

Tags: datepicker, gwtbootstrap3

Requirement : Mask the datepicker on blur / form submit.

I was able to get the masking done onBlur with forceparse set to false but i'm unable to navigate to the next month/year in the datepicker maybe because i'm overriding the DOM handlers.

```
dob.setForceParse(false);
dob.addDomHandler(new BlurHandler() {           
    @Override
    public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {               
        dob.getTextBox().setText(**masked value**);
    }
}, BlurEvent.getType());
dob.addDomHandler(new FocusHandler() {          
    @Override
    public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
        dob.setValue(**unmasked value**);
    }
}, FocusEvent.getType());
```

I am unable to use ChangeDateHandler, since it automatically assumes "1/1/19" as "1/1/1900" and masks the text mid-way of text enter. Is there any other way i can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with `DatePicker`'s `TextBox` you can just hide it and use any other Widget instead.

TextBox is basically used to show the `DatePicker` when is focused, to show selected date and to enter the date manually.

Here is an example code how to use your own `TextBox` with `DatePicker` (I use `VerticalPanel` to show `DatePicker` just below the `TextBox`):

```
VerticalPanel container = new VerticalPanel();

final DatePicker dob = new DatePicker();

// hide DatePicker's TextBox
dob.getTextBox().getElement().getStyle().setDisplay(Display.NONE);

final TextBox box = new TextBox(); 
box.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
        dob.show();
        box.setText("**unmasked value**");
    }
});

dob.addHideHandler(new HideHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onHide(HideEvent hideEvent) {
        box.setText("**masked value**");
    }
});

dob.addChangeDateHandler(new ChangeDateHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onChangeDate(ChangeDateEvent evt) {
        Window.alert("ChangeDateEvent");
    }
});

container.add(box);
container.add(dob);
```

Just notice, that you need to call `dob.show()` when `TextBox` is focused. I also use `DatePicker`'s `HideHandler` instead of `TextBox`'s `BlurHandler` to show masked value but you may change it as you wish.

If you want to change the way of parsing dates like `"1/1/19"`, now you can add your own parser to the `TextBox`.